# Flutter Razorpay not displaying image (logo) on checkout options

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

I am integrating Razorpay in Flutter, I have done all the things successfully but I am getting problem to show image (logo) on checkout dialog of Razorpay.

What I have done is:

```
var options = {
  "key" : "rzp_test_123123123123",
  "amount" : 100,
  "name" : "Sample App",
  "image" : "assets/logo.png",
  "description" : "Payment for the some random product",
  "prefill" : {
    "contact" : "2323232323",
    "email" : "shdjsdh@gmail.com"
  },
  "external" : {
    "wallets" : ["paytm"]
  }
};

try{
  razorpay.open(options);
}catch(e){
  print(e.toString());
}
```

The output that I am getting is:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what will be the right string to give as a path in the **image** key?

I have pasted an image in the **assets** folder directly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried hosting the image and then was able to load it.

```
"image" : "https://razorpay.com/assets/razorpay-glyph.svg"
```

I know this is a workaround but again if you wish to pass this image dynamically you won't be having this file saved in your app, rather would need to load it dynamically from a URL.

In case you wish to set up a fixed logo, u can do the same logging into razorpay.com -> setting -> Configurations.

[image]

Comment: I want to use images from the assets folder only as I don't want to host an image. Is it possible?

Comment: @PratikButani I think this is not possible. As the checkout page is a web-view. And so the web-view won't have access to your local files.

Comment: @PratikButani another workaround that we can use here is, read the image from the path and then base64encode the image and pass